# Layout sections vertically in vertical UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

`section1`   `section2`

`item1`        `item1`

`item2`        `item2`

`item3`        `item3`

I need to layout collection view sections vertically and scroll them vertically. Any ideas?

Comment: User two tables..  ??

Comment: Are the number of sections constant or variable?

Comment: They are constant.